# Excel sheet to be updated weekly with specific data from multiple excel sheets

Tags: python-3.x, excel

Good afternoon :)

I am new at python and I would like to desperately ask for your help, currently I was assigned a task that has the following requirements :

#The script must read,run,extract relevant updated data weekly from a folder that contains multiple excel files.
#The updated data is added on an excel sheet as it follows KPI/SW/WEEK (to be able to check the improvement of KPI's per week
#Requirements are : -to extract and do a graphical representation of the KPI1/SWC/WEEK
#-to extract the KPI 1and 2 + the Average KPI of 1and 2 and to do a graphical representation /SWC/WEEK
#-the graphs should show the results in %
#-from master excel list (the list that need update every week) we extract from column G 2 data /hcp/swc/week and do a graphically representation.
#-all the new RN's will be read and have the exact data extracted to be able to  updated data and added to the master excel sheet.
My code is as it follows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

data_file = 'data/mapping_police_violence_snapshot_061920.xlsx'

# Load the entire workbook.
wb = load_workbook(data_file, data_only=True)

# Load one worksheet.
ws = wb['2013-2019 Killings by State']
all_rows = list(ws.rows)

# Pull information from specific cells.
for row in all_rows[1:5]:
state = row[0].value
percent_aa = int(round(row[3].value, 2) * 100)
percent_aa_victims = int(round(row[4].value, 2) * 100)

print(f"\n{state}")
print(f" {percent_aa}% of residents are African American")
print(f" {percent_aa_victims}% killed by police were African American")
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What isn't working? What is happening vs what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi joshmeranda ,thank you for your reply. My question or my complex question is How can I update a master excel sheet weekly by extracting the data from multiple excel sheet and (this data is specific data ex:KPI1 KPI2 ,Average KPI 1&2) added to the master excel sheet every week also I need to add a new column to the master excel sheet every week.In this new column the new updated data will be added. The data that is extracted  weekly will be graphically represented in % .